# Review plugin with rating of post

Tags: plugins, rating

I want rating system like on wordpress's official site.

Every user while making review can rate post (2) 
and the total rating is displayed near the post (1).

Looks pretty simple but all plugins which I found by  now 
either show only total rating or allow to rate comments of users or to
do whatever else but not these.

Any help is appreciated because I got lost in plugins and think of writing by myself this functionality from scratch.

[image]

Comment: Coding this is relatively easy. Add a custom post metavalue with a key value containing the rating of the post which updates when the user votes. Then display this post using the wp_star_rating() function which is in the core. To stop users from voting twice on the same vote, simply store the post ID in the user's custom metadata (in an array) and do a check on that value when you load up the page. This is a lot more simple than it sounds actually.

Comment: Good, thanks for clarification! After all I came across this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/rate/  . It  does exactly what I described. But you explanation is pretty useful, if you post it as answer I would approve it

Comment: Sure, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a lot of plugins that adds rating type of stars, I would suggest that you code your own. Mainly because most of these are very feature rich with things you will not need.

This is a relatively simple process:

1. Add a custom user metadata using `update_user_meta()`, name it `posts_voted`.
2. Add a custom post meta value using `update_post_meta()`. The string value will be the rating, for example, `4.5`. Name it `post_rating`.
3. Then add rating stars to your single.php using `wp_star_rating()`.
4. When user selects their rating, you should update the user's `post_voted` value and store the post's ID in the array, and then you should use their choice of rating and add a simple algorithm for the `post_rating` value.
5. Finally, on loading the page, do a check if the user's `posts_voted` contains the ID of the post; if it does, disable the voting for this user.

Doesn't this sound a lot better than adding a random plugin that contains tons of unnecessary features?